# Joints for secondary character animation in Unity3D

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I heard there are ways to bind bones to meshes and then insert a Rigidbody + Joints to create automatic secondary motion for things like ponytails, cloth, etc. I am currently trying to do that for a character of mine, but for some reason I cannot get the desired effects.

I currently linked a jaw bone under the head bone, and added a character joint modifier to it with the head bone being the Connected Rigidbody. I expected the motion from the character (currently a Mecanim rig in Unity) to create the main motion, which would in turn make the jaw bone bounce around. Instead, I don't see any movement at all from the jaw bone.

Any ideas? Maybe I am doing it wrong? Maybe I heard wrong and I cannot do it this way?

Thanks in advance!

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Simply removed the jaw from the Mecanim system and added the rigidbody with a Hinged Joint to it. Then added a Rigidbody with no gravity and Frozen XYZ rotation and position to the Head bone. Used the Head's Rigibody as the Jaw's Hinge Joint Connected Body and made tweaks to the settings for desired bounciness... now the jaw responds to the body's motion. Wee!